# I am trying to load a javascript file in to my project but receive the following error

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUpBu.png)

I have a script tag in my html page

```
<script src="angular-footballdata-api-factory.min.js">
```

I placed the file in the scripts folder and added the following code to the BundleConfig page

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryFoot").Include(
                "~/Scripts/angular-footballdata-api-factory.min.js"));
```

And the following code in the _Layout page

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryFoot")
```

Any idea why it can't be found

Answer (score 1):

Remove `<script src="angular-footballdata-api-factory.min.js">` from the html page
`angular-footballdata-api-factory` script will be rendered as part of bundle that you included in layout.

If you want to explicitly load `angular-footballdata-api-factory` js file then remove it from bundle, and use `<script src="~/Scripts/angular-footballdata-api-factory.min.js">`.